# modal pop up with ejs and express

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

So first I'm new to backend and maybe a little confused and I have a project so my confusion is how to connect this:

*modal.ejs*

```
<div class="modal fade text-black" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content position-relative">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button"
                    class="btn-close position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle btn-danger rounded-circle"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                <% if(true) { %>
                    data accepted
                <% }else{ %>
                    data rejected
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*index.html part form*

```
<form class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 form-inline justify-content-center" action="/" method="post">
            <input class="form-control mt-2" id="input" type="text" placeholder="Name of company" name="companyName">
            <input class="form-control mt-3" id="input" type="search" placeholder="https://www.company.com/" name="website">    
            <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 px-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#Modal">Check</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This has worked, but the pop up doesn't appear, instead a new page appears

*app.js*

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const url = {
    name: req.body.companyName,
    link: req.body.website,
  };

  Url.findOne({ website: url.link }, function (err, foundCompany) {
    if (foundCompany) {
      console.log("found in db");
      // res.redirect("/accepted");
      res.render("modal");
    } else {
      const newUrl = new Url({
        name: url.name,
        website: url.link,
      });

      newUrl.save();

      console.log("not found in db");
      // res.redirect("/notaccepted");
    }
  });
});
```

How to make the server to show a modal pop up as a result from a check on the database?
if found data => data found
else => data not found